# Trigger back end printing from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, powershell, crystal-reports

I have an internal `PHP/IIS` based application.
I have a need to have a backend process run `(powershell)` that generates a PDF from Crystal Reports and then sends it to the printer.
I don't want to call the powershell directly from my PHP program because it hangs the browser screen while the back end runs, and rarely does it actually complete the process.

I am running PHP on `IIS/Server2008R2` with `MSSQL2008R2` as my database platform.

I am posting this question, and am going to answer it myself as I figured out how to accomplish this after many hours of research and trial.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of research and frustration, I came up with the following solution that works:

1. I have a powershell script that I built that makes calls to the Crystal Runtime library to generate a PDF file and store it in a folder.
2. I use foxit reader `freader.exe  /t filename PRINTERNAME` to send it to the printer.
3. I setup a cmd  to call the powershell script and to do cleanup. `"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -file c:\pdf.ps\ProcessQueue.ps1`
4. I setup a task scheduler entry triggered by event id 17061, Source MSSQLSERVER ,  that calls my command file.
5. From my PHP front end, I submit a sql query: `xp_logevent 55555,'Print Job Requested',Informational`

SQL Server raises the eventlog entry, which triggers the scheduled task, which runs my script on the back end.  The script checks the printQueue table in the database, builds the pdf, and prints it.

Because of permissions issues, you cannot get PHP to log to EventLOG directly.

Thanks to the many others on this site for all the great information.  Hopefully this helps out someone else who is struggling with this problem.